# ASP.NET Entity Framework Update SQL set int value to 0

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a SQL column as an int data type.

I'm trying to update en entry using Entity Framework, setting it's value to 0 but it does not get updated. I also don't get an error when Submitting Changes... Odd. Well I changed the Tag Name and set the count to 0, the name got updated but the count was not modified

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Code Snipet:

Add Tag - up the tag count:

```
  Tag tag = _tagsRepository.GetTagByName(TagName);
  if (tag == null)
  {
      tag = new Tag();
      tag.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
      tag.Name = TagName;
      tag.Count = 1;
  }
  else
  {
      tag.Count += 1;
  }
  tag = _tagsRepository.SaveTag(tag);
```

Remove tag from an item, update the tag count

```
   Tag tag = _tagsRepository.GetTagByName(TagName);
   if (tag != null)
   {
       tag.Count -= 1;
   }
   tag = _tagsRepository.SaveTag(tag);
```

GetTagByName Method

```
    public Tag GetTagByName(string Name)
    {
        Tag result = null;
        using (ISADataContext dc = conn.GetContext())
        {
            result = dc.Tags.Where(t => t.Name == Name).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

SaveTag Method

```
public Tag SaveTag(Tag tag)
{
    using (ISADataContext dc = conn.GetContext())
    {
        if (tag.TagID > 0)
        {
            dc.Tags.Attach(new Tag { TagID = tag.TagID });
            dc.Tags.ApplyCurrentValues(tag);
        }
        else
        {
            dc.Tags.AddObject(tag);
        }
        dc.SaveChanges();
    }
    return tag;
}
```

Workaround:

```
using (ISADataContext dc = conn.GetContext())
{
    if (tag.TagID > 0)
    {
        if (tag.Count == 0)
        {
            Tag t =  dc.Tags.Where( tt=> tt.TagID == tag.TagID).First();
            t.Count = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            dc.Tags.Attach(new Tag { TagID = tag.TagID });
            dc.Tags.ApplyCurrentValues(tag);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dc.Tags.AddObject(tag);
    }
    dc.SaveChanges();
}
return tag;
```

Comment: Please show `_tagsRepository.GetTagByName(TagName)` definition.

Comment: I think your `conn.GetContext()` is creating the problem. I guess, the context is different in `get` and `save` function. That's why instead of updating Tag, it adds a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't wrap your `DataContext` in using statements in your scenario. Doing this means that you're retrieving the object in one `context` and trying to save the existing object in a new `context`. This means that when you're trying to save in the second `context`, it has no idea that the object already exists in the database.

Comment: It works whenever I use a value other than 0, I checked and when modifying the Name column as well as setting the Count column to 0 and attaching and running ApplyCurrentValues it updates the Name but the Count column is not affected...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem as yours - every other value except 0 works fine. Can we get some solution to this?

EDIT: After some research, I found a way to fix this. You have to modify this line:

```
dc.Tags.Attach(new Tag { TagID = tag.TagID });
```

In the stub object, add the problematic property (in your case Count) and set its value to something that is never possible in the db, for example -2. In this way, the EF context will also compare the count value of the attached object and will always know there is a difference. So your line becomes:

```
dc.Tags.Attach(new Tag { TagID = tag.TagID, Count = -2 });
```

I am not sure if this will work every time, but for now it seems to do the job.